# Сравнение двух столбцов и вывод уникальных строк в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть четыре столбца:

1. Логин студента
2. номер вопроса по тесту
3. оценка преподавателя
4. оценка студента

В базе данных хранится порядка 50000 строк.

Есть правильная оценка (пусть будет к примеру) 0 и 1 (это оценка преподавателя)
Есть оценка студента  также 1 и 0.

Нужно сравнить оценку студента с оценкой преподавателя в случае не совпадения нужно вывести список студентов которые хуже всего справились с конкретным вопросом и с заданием в целом. Прощу помощи.

Comment: Решайте задачу по очереди, сначала выбираете записи которые вообще должны попадать в результат видимо проверяя на неравенство оценки. потом группируете их до студентов, вопросов, заданий. Если после этого что то еще не получается пишите сюда до чего вы уже дошли. Т.е. приводите здесь структуру таблицы с тестовыми данными, результат который необходим и тот запрос который у вас уже получился для работы с этими данными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ответа на Ваш вопрос пришлось набросать пример. Создаем таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  `loginStudent` varchar(10), -- Логин студента
  `questionNumber` int, -- Номер вопроса
  `ratingTeacher` bit, -- оценка преподавателя
  `ratingStudent` bit); -- оценка студента
```

Заполняем таблицу значениями:

```
INSERT INTO Test (
  `loginStudent`, 
  `questionNumber`, 
  `ratingTeacher`,
  `ratingStudent`)
VALUES
  ('denis', 1, 1, 1),
  ('denis', 2, 1, 1),
  ('denis', 3, 0, 1),
  ('denis', 4, 1, 0),
  ('denis', 4, 0, 1),
  ('mark', 1, 1, 1),
  ('mark', 2, 1, 1),
  ('mark', 3, 0, 0),
  ('mark', 4, 0, 1),
  ('mark', 4, 1, 0),
  ('ann', 1, 0, 1),
  ('ann', 1, 1, 0),
  ('ann', 1, 0, 1),
  ('ann', 2, 1, 0),
  ('ann', 3, 1, 0),
  ('ann', 4, 0, 1);
```

Конечно не 50К, но этого достаточно, чтобы увидеть результат. Пишем запрос `SELECT` на выборку необходимых записей:

```
SELECT
  loginStudent,
  count(*) as 'Количество не совпавших'
FROM
  Test
WHERE
  ratingTeacher <> ratingStudent -- у кого не совпала оценка
GROUP BY
  loginStudent -- группируем по студенту
HAVING 
   count(*) > 0 -- у кого кол-во не совпавших больше 0
   -- (можно менять эту величину или не писать вовсе, для Вашего вопроса можно не писать) 
order by 
  count(*) desc -- сортируем по убыванию. Первая строка - больше всех не совпала
```

Видим соответствующий результат, кто хуже всех справился с заданием в общем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Студентка *ann* больше всех ошиблась, шесть раз, это общий результат.

---

Напишем немного другой запрос, в котором посмотрим, на какие именно вопросы отвечают хуже всего и кто.

```
SELECT
  loginStudent,
  questionNumber,
  count(ratingTeacher <> ratingStudent) as 'Количество не совпавших'
FROM
  Test
WHERE
  ratingTeacher <> ratingStudent -- у кого не совпала оценка
GROUP BY -- группируем
  loginStudent, -- по студенту
  questionNumber -- вопросу
HAVING 
   count(ratingTeacher <> ratingStudent) > 0 
   -- у кого кол-во не совпавших больше 0
order by 
  count(ratingTeacher <> ratingStudent) desc, 
  questionNumber,
  loginStudent
```

Смотрим результат, кто справился хуже всех с конкретным вопросом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом результате видно, что студентка *Ann* трижды ошиблась в первом вопросе, ну и *mark* с *denis* ошиблись в четвертом по два раза, ну и единичные ошибки.

---

Раз уж нам нужно все и сразу, то используем алиасы и подзапрос. Напишем вот такой запрос, который будет добавлять дополнительную информацию к нашему второму запросу:

```
  SELECT
    r.loginStudent,
    r.questionNumber,
    count(r.ratingTeacher <> r.ratingStudent) as 'Количество не совпавших',
    (select count(*) from Test t where t.loginStudent = r.loginStudent and
     t.ratingTeacher <> t.ratingStudent) as 'Всего ошибок' -- подзапрос
    -- в подзапросе нужны Alias-ы, так как таблицы совпадают и имена столбцов одинаковые
  FROM
    Test r -- r - псевдоним для данной таблицы (Alias)
  WHERE
    r.ratingTeacher <> r.ratingStudent -- у кого не совпала оценка
  GROUP BY -- группируем
    r.loginStudent, -- по студенту
    r.questionNumber -- по вопросу
  HAVING 
     count(r.ratingTeacher <> r.ratingStudent) > 0 
     -- у кого кол-во не совпавших больше 0
  order by 
    count(r.ratingTeacher <> r.ratingStudent) desc, 
    -- сортируем по убыванию. Первая строка - больше всех не совпала
    r.questionNumber,
    r.loginStudent
```

И тут мы уже видим немного другую таблицу результатов, в которой видим сколько ошибок в конкретном вопросе и сколько ошибок всего у студента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Количество не совпавших* - это у нас количество ошибок в вопросе. То есть, сколько ошибок в конкретном вопросе у конкретного студента. Такая таблица сразу говорит, кто и сколько раз ошибся в конкретном вопросе, кто ошибся больше всех и общая статистика ошибок в последнем столбце.

Comment: @redcoub, а это не то, что Вам было нужно?

Comment: именно то, тем более в различных вариантах.  Большое спасибо еще раз. Если у Вас найдется время, не сочтите за наглость, помогите еще по одному вопросу. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623362/Среднее-значение-из-таблицы-sql

Comment: @redcoub, как будет время, гляну. Если будет ответ - отвечу, конечно

Answer (score 0):

столбцы таблицы T1:
Login, Ask, Value1,Value2

```
SELECT Login, COUNT(ask) as Rating
FROM T1
WHERE Value1=Value2
GROUP BY Login
ORDER BY COUNT(ask)
```

"которые хуже всего справились с конкретным вопросом":

```
GROUP BY Login, Ask
```