# Среднее значение из таблицы sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть задача сформировать базу для личных целей.
Исходные данные
более 2000 заданий
5 работников
2 вида оценок:

> 1) Оценка качества по шкале супер,отл,хор,удов,неуд,ужас,срам.
>   2) Во второй шкале оценок 6 видов оценок пусть будет 1,2,3,4,5,6.

**Вопрос : как определить итоговую оценку по заданию по оценке
 большинства рабочих. Вопрос 2: Как определить самые сложные задания?**

К примеру все 5 поставили оценку. Или 2 человека одну оценку а остальные разные( оценка двух человек будет правильной)
и еще 1 вариант итоговой оценки : средняя оценка пример: если оценки большинства не существует, то оценка формируется следующим образом двое поставили хор двое поставили неуд значит оценка будет удов.

***Примечание: Вторая шкала практически нигде не учитывается!***

Пример таблицы:

```html
INSERT INTO Test (
  `zadanie`,
  `Id_Otcenki`, 
  `login`, 
  `otsenka1`,
  `otsenka2`)
VALUES
  (1,1,denis,хор,2),
  (2,1,denis,ужас,1),
  (3,2,denis,хор,3),
  (4,1,denis,супер,1),
  (1,2,sergey,хор,2),
  (2,2,sergey,удов,1),
  (3,1,sergey,отл,3),
  (4,2,sergey,супер,1),
  (1,3,denis,удов,2),
  (2,3,denis,ужас,1),
  (3,3,denis,хор,3),
  (4,3,denis,супер,1),
  (1,4,tim,ужас,2),
  (2,4,tim,срам,1),
  (3,4,tim,отл,3),
  (4,4,tim,супер,1),
  (1,5,alex,супер,2),
  (2,5,alex,удов,1),
  (3,5,alex,неуд,3),
  (4,5,alex,супер,1),
```

На выходе нужно получить, что то типо этого:

> Номер задания: итоговая оценка

- 1:хор
- 2:неуд
- 3:хор
- 4:супер

Comment: Это задание для участников ruSO потестировать их скилл? Или у вас есть с чем-то проблемы?

Comment: В скиле участников я не сомневаюсь.

Comment: Все значения я смог разбить по таблицам. К тому же еще с одним заданием здесь же помогли.

Comment: Ну и одно задание сам сделал, но вот с этим у меня ступор. Да и знаний в sql особых нет. В

Comment: кажется я не увидел вопросы в цитате....надо бы их оттуда вынуть.....если они это то, что вы хотите узнать...а то так непонятно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исправил, вроде теперь их лучше видно.

Comment: У вас 7 текстовых оценок и 6 цифровых. Нельзя ли сделать это количество одинаковым для простоты и иметь только цифровую оценку, и по ней выводить текстовую 1 => 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется вот это подойдет:

```
SELECT zadanie, FLOOR(AVG(CASE otsenka1 
     WHEN 'супер' THEN 6 
     WHEN 'отл' THEN 5 
     WHEN 'хор' THEN 4 
     WHEN 'удов' THEN 3 
     WHEN 'неуд' THEN 2 
     WHEN 'ужас' THEN 1 
     WHEN 'срам' THEN 0
     END)) FROM Test GROUP BY zadanie`
```

Группирует по заданию, переводит содержимое `otsenka1` в цифровой эквивалент, вычисляет средне-арифметическое и округляет вниз. В итоге получается задание и цифровая оценка.

Comment: А как быть если оценка как раз таки текстовая?

Comment: Из Вашего примера следует, что `otsenka2` числовая и всегда присутствует. Среднее арифметическое из текстовой оценки взять невозможно... Вам надо убедиться, что в таблицу обязательно попадает цифровой эквивалент оценки.

Comment: эмммм собственно вторая оценка менее всего интересна. Писал в примечании(сейчас выделили курсивом и жирным)

Comment: Ну, как я сказал, Вам надо сделать так, чтобы цифровой эквивалент был всегда. Если его нет, то можно использовать конструкцию `CASE WHEN END` для замены.

Comment: А есть ли вариант приравнять текстовые оценки к цифровым и вывести как вы предложили?

Comment: изменил ответ с `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Странно, что подошло) в задании вроде написано, что "среднее" оценок (1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) будет 1